# Listview display of sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a database that I have created with the following handler:

```
    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "trade.db";
    public static final String RESOURCEID = "resourceid";
    public static final String STARTPRICE = "startprice";
    public static final String CURRENTBID = "currentbid";
    public static final String EXPIRES = "expires";
    public static final String BUYNOWPRICE = "buynowprice";
    public static final String TYPE = "type";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE cards (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, resourceid TEXT, startprice TEXT,currentbid TEXT, expires TEXT, buynowprice TEXT, type TEXT);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        android.util.Log.w("cards",
                "Upgrading database, which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

I would like to display the items of this DB in a listview where items are selectable, unfortunately I am a complete android nooby (first application). Could someone please explain to me how I would do this? I am well aware there are some examples out there, but I am simply unable to follow them. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tutorial, just some things you'll need:

- [The
  `getReadableDatabase()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase%28%29) of
  your `SQLiteOpenHelper`
- [A CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html)

Answer (score 0):

I can give you full example of how to show it... But it would make you a lazy... Whatever I can guide you... Like you have to create a layout for `ListView` and the layout for the items of `ListView`... You can do this also without creating these layouts... But whatever that is you need to create an `adapter`  it could be `SimpleAdapter`... You have to put that adapter's record by `HashMap`... Like the example below:

```
 
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,appntmntHistoryList,R.layout.appointment_history_text,new String[] {"date","appntmnt_id"},new int[] {R.id.appDateHist, R.id.appWithFakeHist});
appointmentHistory.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This process is for record fetching from database store those records in key/value pair by

```
HashMap
```

...

Comment: Although this consumes more memory then simply using a CursorAdapter to show results from a Database-query.

Comment: Ok... As chris is completely noob... It is better to try just the simpler one... Isn't it???

Comment: I am only planning on having a maximum of 30 records in the db, so I don't think memory should be such a large issue.
In simple terms, the adapter is to convert the db to a format that listview would like?

Comment: My example will work for any simple recordsets... Try to work on it for understanding...

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try to figure it out after the formula 1, more than 30 hours of coding in 50 hours of being awake kills the soul :P
Thanks very much for the input guys, would you mind checking the thread again tomorrow after I have had time to have a look and attempt an implementation.

Comment: Started a new thread to avoid confusion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649071/sqlite-display-in-list-what-am-i-doing-wrong